# I want to add smiley on add to cart pop up window using Jquery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

please check this link:

http://wzfxp.felau.servertrust.com/SearchResults.asp?Cat=1817

click on add to cart button.

the it show add to cart popup window.I want to add smiley face on that popup.Remember I dont have code of add to cart means I cant change that code only I can access its id's and classes.Only after doing view source I can see code or script for that.
How to do it??

Comment: If you can't change the codes, there will be no possibility to do so. What do you mean by "I only can access its id's and classes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

**JavaScript**

`$('.soft_add_action_area').css('background', 'url("http://www.mangolanguages.com/assets/images/icon_smiley.png?1285256212") no-repeat left center');`

in

- Google Chrome's Developer tools or
- Mozilla Firefox's Firebug

**CSS**

```
.soft_add_action_area {
   background : url("http://www.mangolanguages.com/assets/images/icon_smiley.png?1285256212") no-repeat left center
}
```

Let me know if it need any modifications.